# Makefile error: build.make:3687: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: c, cmake, makefile

I am getting the following error running `cmake`

```
/build.make:3687: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Line 3687 that has the error:

```
game_rUnversioned directory_32_OBJECTS = \
```

What is wrong there?

Comment: Perhaps there is some space or tab after the `\\`

Comment: The `Unversioned directory` seems suspicious. Very probably, the `build.make` is some generated thing (e.g. by `cmake`), and you should give much more context and explain how it was generated. If you are compiling some free software, please name it. So please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: Make sure you're using tabs for indentation. Using mixed tabs & spaces might cause such an error.

Comment: Ah, so this is **CMake**, not **make**. That's a huge difference, you know? Don't look at the generated Makefiles **at all**, that will **not** help you. They are supposed to be black boxes (because, after all, they could be KDevelop project files etc. just as well). Look at the **CMake** output to figure out what went wrong **generating** those Makefiles.

Comment: Is there a specific thing I need to look at in CMake? I don't know because there is no error referring to a specific line or something that I could look at inside CMake, I'm afraid I cannot post it here publicly due to copyright concerns..

Comment: If you cannot show code here, you are asking at the wrong place. Ask privately some colleague working on the same code base.

Comment: @CodeFreaks: CMake takes the settings in `CMakeLists.txt` and *generates* whatever build files you asked for, which might be Makefiles, NMake files, a MSVC solution or whatever. This process is (generally) well-tested and reliable. If it results in broken Makefiles, this is much more likely due to an error in your CMakeLists.txt than due to a CMake error. At the very least, we'd like to know where this "Unversioned directory" part comes from, the `cmake` command line you used to configure your build, and the output from CMake, because **that's** where it likely went wrong.

Comment: The space in that assignment is almost certainly the problem. Fix that and I bet the problem goes away. make **does not** like spaces in filenames and **cannot** work with them.

Comment: Can u please point out what do you mean by / where is that - assignment?

Comment: Check you have tabs (not spaces) in front of make commands.  This is a common error with make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate answer is, you cannot create variable names that contain whitespace.  That's not valid in (newer versions of) make.  So this:

```
game_rUnversioned directory_32_OBJECTS = \
```

is not a valid variable assignment because of the space (it has nothing to do with the backslash).

The longer answer is that your script `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/svn_version.sh` which is apparently supposed to print the SVN version, is instead printing the string `Unversioned directory`.  You'll have to figure out why that is and get that script to print the right value, or at least ensure that whatever value it prints is a single word and does NOT contain whitespace, before this will work.

*ETA:*

If you want to make this work in a directory which is not an SVN workspace, you'll need to fix the `svn_version.sh` script so it can handle the case where it can't find a version.  Rewrite that script something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

ver=$(svnversion -n -c game | cut -d':' -f2)
case $ver in
    (*\ *) echo unknown ;;
    (*)    echo "$ver" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

This ensures that if the `game` directory isn't an SVN directory, it will print a value that doesn't contain any spaces (`unknown`) and this means your makefiles won't break.

Comment: It turns out that CMake is generating invalid files so-to-speak,so it's useless to look at build.make, since it will be replaced once I run `make` again. As for SVN I'm still very confused about how can I fix that, makes it clear why I'm requesting help from you guys here.. I regret not having enough points to up-vote this informative answer though.

Comment: I never said "look at build.make".  CMake is absolutely NOT generating invalid files... or rather, it's doing so because you're giving it invalid input.  GIGO.  If you fix your `svn_version.sh` script, then things will work.  That's where your problem is, that script: everything else is irrelevant.  Since you haven't provided us with any details about how the `svn_version.sh` script works we can't help with that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont know what I should or should not provide excuse my stupidity. This is svn_version.sh script: `#!/bin/bash
eval "svnversion -n -c game | cut -d':' -f2"
`

Comment: That's a ... weird ... script.  Anyway, the problem is that when you run `svnversion -n -c game` it's supposed to print the SVN version of that directory (something like `r45` or whatever), but instead it's printing `Unversioned directory`.  Are you running this from an SVN workspace?  If I run `svnversion -n -c foo` for some local directory foo which is not part of an SVN workspace, then I get the same behavior you see (the output is `Unversioned directory`).

Comment: Off-course it generated invalid files... how would you interpret that error then.. build.make is generated by CMake, and it has that freaking error.. Im confused and Im giving up already, a moderator can take care of this question cuz I know nobody is going to be able to help me. Thanks for ur attemps (?).

Comment: Hey bro would u be able to speak to me on Skype please?? My id is gunsnglory -- I hope that's all right for rules.

Comment: Sorry, I don't Skype.  I've already explained what's wrong, multiple times.  The `svn_version.sh` script is supposed to print the SVN version of the `game` directory, but instead it's printing an error `Unversioned directory`.  That is causing all your problems.  Forget cmake, makefiles, etc.  If you solve this problem with `svn_version.sh` then everything will work properly.  It's most likely printing that message because your directory is not actually an SVN workspace, or else `game` is not checked into SVN as a versioned directory (do you know what SVN is?)

Comment: I know too little about SVN, I know that it is a version control system, actually no my directory is not a SVN workspace, neither is game checked into SVN. I'm running on FreeBSD, but i havent found any tutorials to help me with a proper configuration for SVN. How can I do that?? Thanks alot!

Comment: That's a completely different question which you should ask with different tags on SO (but first, of course, try to figure it out yourself by reading the docs, tutorials, etc. you can find online).  However, this code absolutely _requires_ that the current directory be a SVN workspace, or it will not work.  I'll suggest a change to the `svn_version.sh` script that will fix this.

Comment: Thank you for keeping up with me man, I will try to find a good tutorial now to make my directory a SVN workspace. Thanks.

Comment: SHIIIT!!! YOU ROCK DUDEEe!!! U WERE RIGHT! PROBLEM SOLVED!!! Finally compiling without any problems, I can't thank you enough !!!!!!! IM SO HAPPY!!

Answer (score 0):

That bare backslash looks very suspicious. That will be interpreted by Make as an attempt to [continue that line on the next](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Splitting-Lines) (physical) line, so what does that line contain?

Comment: So CMake generated the Makefile?  In that case you need to fix the CMake files.

Comment: @CodeFreaks: It's suspicious because you probably **don't** actually have a directory named "game_rUnversioned directory_32" in your source tree. Where did CMake get that idea from?